# Текстовый редактор на С++

Tags: c++

Есть потребность в максимально простом текстовом редакторе. Объясню суть - хочу написать собственный консольный текстовый редактор на с++, чтобы задать его как стандартный для коммитов git. Vim, nano и все остальные не подходят из-за не самого простого интерфейса, отсутвия поддержки курсора - все приходится делать только стрелочками, из-за чего и корректировать коммит не всегда удобно и что-то из него копировать. Нужно пару советов:

1. Что вообще из себя представляет архитектура
2. Как git взаимодействует с редактором, и что нужно, чтобы мой мог это делать
3. Полезные источники, в интернете особо ничего нет, все пишут просто редактор - открыл файл, написал, сохранил

Comment: _Как git взаимодействует с редактором_ - никак. Он просто его запускает.

Comment: Посмотрите на [Tk text widget](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html). Попробуйте перенести его в консоль (обратите внимание, что tcl/Tk реализованы на библиотечном коде, который можно вызывать прямо из C/C++)

Comment: Nano умеет в примитивное управление мышкой, с флагом `-m`. Ну и вообще, есть же графические редакторы. Можно VSCode к гиту подцепить.

Comment: *"все пишут просто редактор - открыл файл, написал, сохранил"* - а оно так и работает